# iOS-Charts space left and right

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I want insert space left and right to prevent value label prevent yAxis value. And remove background line under charts.
How can I do?

**Edit**

```
    self.lineChart.delegate = self;
    self.lineChart.descriptionText = @"";
    self.lineChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    self.lineChart.scaleXEnabled = NO;
    self.lineChart.scaleYEnabled = NO;
    self.lineChart.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.30f;
```

[image]

Comment: can you paste your chart setup code?

Comment: @AmitKalghatgi I've edited mi question with setup code

Answer (score 2):

On Charts 3.0 you can use...

lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMin = 0.2 
lineChartView.xAxis.spaceMax = 0.2

...to add some space on left and right.

Comment: it's not worked when we add in viewdidload.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background line under the charts use below code :

```
_lineChart.yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
_lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add spacing - you can use Charts 3.0, and adjust `xAxis.axisMinimum`/`xAxis.axisMaximum`.

To adjust the background, simply use the `UIView`'s properties of `backgroundColor`, `opaque` etc.

To disable the grid - adjust the `drawGridLinesEnabled` on the axes, as @ashmi123 said.